# Find if a string contains substring python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to find a substring with regex in python inside an input.
What I mean is that I'm getting an input string from the user, and I have JSON file I load, inside every block in my JSON file I have 'alert_regex', and I want to check it the string inside my input contains my regex.

this is what I have tried so far:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
import re

# Load json file
json_data=open('alerts.json')
jdata = json.load(json_data)
json_data.close()

# Input for users
input = 'Check Liveness in dsadakjnflkds.server'

# Search in json function
def searchInJson(input, jdata):
    for i in jdata:
        # checks if the input is similiar for the alert name in the json
        print(i["alert_regex"])
        regexCheck = re.search(i["alert_regex"], input)

        if(regexCheck):
            # saves and prints the confluence's related link
            alert = i["alert_confluence"]
            print(alert)
            return print('Alert successfully found in `alerts.json`.')
    print('Alert was not found!')

searchInJson(input,jdata)
```

what I want my regex to check is only if the string contains 'Check flink liveness'

There are 2 optional problems:
1. maybe my regex is not correct inside i["alert_regex"] (I've tried to same one with javascript and it worked)
2. my code is not correct.

An example of my JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "alert_regex": "check (.*) Liveness (.*)",
        "alert_confluence": "link goes here"
    }
]
```

Comment: The way to check if string `x` contains substring `y` is to check `y in x`. There is no need for any regex.

Comment: You should include a minimal example of `jdata` with items that should produce a match with the string.

Comment: Your regex pattern isn't matching the `input` example. Should it have? Did you try alternatives in an online (python flavored) regex tester?

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. All of your code can be reduced down to:

```
import re
re.search("check (.*) Liveness (.*)", 'Check Liveness in dsadakjnflkds.server')
```

This will not match because:

1. You need to set the "case insensitivity" on the search because `check` will not match with `Check` otherwise.
2. `check (.*) Liveness` ends up with two spaces between `check` and `Liveness` if `(.)` matches the empty string.

You need:

```
re.search("check (.*)Liveness (.*)", 'Check Liveness in dsadakjnflkds.server', flags=re.I)
```